# hindi ttf file not working while sending google cloud notification messages in hindi

Tags: android, textview, truetype, custom-font

I want to show hindi text in notification panel but as i am sending hindi text through my web portal then android application text view is showing garbage value type characters even if my i am using Typeface fonts

This is the text that i am sending from the portal

[image]

Now this is the text that i am receiving at notification panel

[image]

And this is the text which is shown in my notification activity

[image]

Below is my code sample of textview

```
Typeface hindiTypeface;
 public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            hindiTypeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"hindi2.ttf");
            heading= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeading);
            message= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
            image= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
            heading.setTypeface(hindiTypeface);
            message.setTypeface(hindiTypeface);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use ttf fonts,the error is in your backend code..You may be receiving unicode from your server.Just convert it using Html.fromHtml(message);